# jQuery - How to select elements that do NOT have a class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, traversal

How do I get elements that do not have any class names?

```
        <td class="B A">A03<sub>reserved</sub></td>
        <td class="B R">R70</td>
        <td>105</td>
        <td class="M C">L220</td>
```

Right now I'm doing this `$('td').not('.A, .B, .C, .M, .R')`

There's gotta be a better way!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector with a blank value:

```
$('[class=]')
```

Comment: Arrgghh...  I was so close!  Kept trying $('td[class=" "]') and other things to select nothing.  Your answer was perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: something about that unbalanced equals sign just seems to strike a nerve with me ;)  I'd agree this is the best answer, however.

Answer (score 7):

how about this:

```
$("td:not([class])")
```

not sure if it'll work for something like:

```
<td class="">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `filter()`:

```
$("td").filter( function() {return this.className=='';} )
```

Comment: @Tomalak:  this isn't just a sympathy note :) I had actually forgotten about the '==' which ended up helping me achieve something else on this current project.  so...Kudos!